# Numpy insert matrix values with matrix index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have the following code which creates a 4D `grid` matrix and I am looking to insert the rolled 2D `vals` matrix into this grid.

```
import numpy as np

k = 100
x = 20
y = 10
z = 3

grid = np.zeros((y, k, x, z))
insert_map = np.random.randint(low=0, high=y, size=(5, k, x))
vals = np.random.random((5, k))

for i in range(x):
    grid[insert_map[:, :, i], i, 0] = np.roll(vals, i)
```

If `vals` would be a 1D array and I would use a 1D `insert_map` array as a reference it would work, however using it in multiple dimensions seems to be an issue and it raises error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (5,100)  could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (5,100,3)
```

I'm confused as to why it's saying that error as `grid[insert_map[:, :, i], i, 0]` should in my mind give a (5, 100) insert location for the `y` and `k` portion of the grid array and then fixes the `x` and `z` portion with `i` and `0`?

Is there any way to insert the 2D (5, 100) rolled `vals` matrix into the 4D (10, 100, 20, 3) `grid` matrix by 2D indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid` is `(y, k, x, z)`

`insert_map` is `(5, k, x)`.  `insert_map[:, :, i]` is then `(5,k)`.

`grid[insert_map[:, :, i], i, 0]` will then be `(5,k,z)`.  `insert_map[]` only indexes the first `y` dimension.

`vals` is `(5,k)`; `roll` doesn't change that.

`np.roll(vals, i)[...,None]` can broadcast to fill the `z` dimension, if that's what you want.

Your `insert_map` can't select values along the `k` dimension.  It's values, created by the `randint` are valid the `y` dimension.

If the `i` and `0` are supposed to apply to the last two dimensions, you still need an index for the `k` dimension.  Possibilities are:

```
grid[insert_map[:, j, i], j, i, 0]
grid[insert_map[:, :, i], 0, i, 0]
grid[insert_map[:, :, i], :, i, 0]
grid[insert_map[:, :, i], np.arange(k), i, 0]
```